# Calculate field not working in Modelbuilder using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I am trying to do a very simple calculation in ModelBuilder, where I use **Add Field** to generate a column with for volume data. I use **Calculate field** where I select the volume column as "field name", python as "expression type" and use the following code `$feature.POLY_AREA * 0.5`.

When I run it I get this error:

> ERROR 000539:   File "", line 1
>
> ```
> $feature.POLY_AREA * 0.5
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax  Failed to execute (Calculate Field (5)).
> ```

I did this in ArcMap and it worked without any issue.

Comment: Ensure the language is set to Arcade in Calculate Field tool. Also what do you it worked in "ArcMap", this is an Arcade expression and that can only mean it is in ArcPro?

Comment: I can only choose VB, Python, Python 9.3 and Name (Model variable) in "expression type". How do I select "Arcade"? 
The expression worked in ArcMap excluding "$feature."

Comment: You didn't say that in your question that you dropped off half of the expression ($feature)... So sounds like you are running the tool in ArcMap but what you are showing is an Arcade expression which is meant to be run in ArcPro. I suspect you don't have a field called POLY_AREA in the dataset you are attempting to run this on in ArcPro.

Comment: To really clarify what it is you are running it on you need to edit your question and show us the full set of fields in the attribute table you are executing the tool on.